# How to redirect docker build output to a file?

Tags: docker, logging, build

I'm trying to store the logs of the build process in a file from this command for example:

```sh
docker build -t python:3.8.5 . --progress=plain
```

Would expect to work with this command:

```sh
docker build -t python:3.8.5 . --progress=plain >> builder.log
```

Can't find in the doc how to do it.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use:

```
docker build -t python:3.8.5 . --progress=plain > builder.log 2>&1
```

to redirect both stderr and stdout to builder.log